# Оформление кода в Microsoft Word

Tags: java, ms-word

Можно ли и какими средствами оформить java код в документе Microsoft Word?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Надо написать красявый отчет начальству или там преподам - так я понимаю? Делается так:

1. Запускаем [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
2. Загружаем файлик и набираем File->Export to HTML...
3. Далее полученный HTML загружаем в Word и получаем очень презентабельный код, с подсвеченными ключевыми словами, а если надо и с номерами строк.
4. Если форматирование кода не нравится, то можно подобрать через все тот же IDEA (через File->Settings->Code style) стиль кода, шрифты, переносы, фигурные скобки и проч.

**Update**
Для поклонников Eclipse - есть плагин [Java2HTML](http://www.java2html.de/eclipse.html) или же его версия в виде отдельного Java приложения, которое также генерирует HTML

Answer (score 3):

Провел эксперимент:

1. Открыл IE
2. Открыл вопрос на хэшкоде, любой, там где код раскрашен.
3. Выделил код, нажал ctrl-c
4. В ворде нажал ctrl-v
5. Профит

Иными словами отстайлить код в html'е, его в ворде открыть...

Comment: спасибо! я кстати вчера примерно так и сделал, "отформатил" в pastebin и скопировал в Word =) Подсветка синтаксиса сохранилась!

Answer (score 1):

я так понимаю тут вопрос стоит в привязке к IDE с которым вы работаете.

я работаю с eclipse, и для меня проблема решается так: код копирую прямо с IDE в word (он копируется вместе с форматированием). есть только один нюанс: если вы вставляете одну строчку или очень маленький кусочек (напр. имя переменной) в таком случае код получается с синим фоном (где синий фон, скорее за все это выделение). баг это или фича я не знаю :)

Comment: ок, спасибо! Ну так тоже не плохо, вроде как выделение кода =)